# Jetty does not remove closed sockets -> connections with same port fail

Tags: java, http, tcp, jetty, wireshark

We are facing an issue with our Jetty Server, where SYN packages during connection build up won't be ACK'ed by Jetty. We could narrow down, that this only happens with SYN packages, which are transmitted via a client port, that was previously used for another connection to Jetty.
As I can see in the Log, the previous connection was closed and FIN ACK was submitted by Client and Server.
Important to say: Not all connections with a "used" port will be ignored, but most will. There are instances of SYN packages being ACK'ed by the server, when the are transmitted via a used port. However, I can not determine any difference between these cases.

I am left with my current assumption, that the Sockets are not properly closed and some involved parties in this mess will ignore or essentially decline the connection, because they still see the closed socket.

In the cases where it doesn't work, there is literally nothing in Jetty's debug logs. In my Wireshark traces I can see, that the SYN pack is retransmitted 2 times (so a total of 3 times) and then the client states 408 (timeout).

We use
Jetty: v9.4.38,
Java: Oracle JRE Version 1.8.0.202,
Javax Servlet: v3.1.0

Does anyone have an idea or similar situation? Is the ACK transmitted by Jetty or by some standard Java implementation?

Comment: Java 8u202 has issues, upgrade.  There's been some major rewrites of the networking layer in Java 8 from about 8u252 thru 8u292 to update the networking stack to be nearly as robust as the Java 11 series.  Also, Jetty 9.4.38 has an SSL buffer bug, upgrade that to at least 9.4.41 (or 9.4.42).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try this out!